# Roles Create New DataBase When I Add a user to a role in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

i create my own database and add user identity table to this by change the connection string.
now my connection string is this:

when i create a new user it worked well.
but when i change the  Register(RegisterViewModel model) in  RegisterControler to add a user to a role like this code:
      public async Task Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

```
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //add user to member role******************
                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Member"))
                    Roles.CreateRole("Member");
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Email, "Member");
                //*******************************************

                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

user registerd but dont add to member Role! and it seem there is another connection string for Roles! beacause whene run this code ASPNETDB.MDF created in App_Data!

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create roles in asp.net identity, you need to use AspNetRoleManager same as you are currently using AspNetUserManager.

The AspNetUserManager may looks like below.

```
public class AspNetRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>
    {
        public AspNetRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
            : base(roleStore)
        {
        }

        public static AspNetRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AspNetRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new AspNetRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>(context.Get<YourDataContext>()));
        }
    }
```

Then you need to register AspNetRoleManager in the owin startup. Same like the AspNetUserManager.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<AspNetRoleManager>(AspNetRoleManager.Create);
```

After that you can use it inside the controller to create roles.

var roleManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get();

// Check for existing roles

```
var roleManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<AspNetRoleManager>();
var roleExists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Member");

if (!roleExists)
{
     var role = new IdentityRole();
     role.Name = "Member";
     var result = roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
}
```

Then add new role to the user.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
var roleRsult = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, roleName);
```

Comment: it is not my question answare, however it seems true but i cant underestand your answare, please help me abuot my question.

Comment: I think you got this wrong, as you are trying to use old stuff of the asp.net membership "Roles.AddUserToRole". My code is for asp.net identity which you should use in your MVC 5 stuff. Actually I am answering your question, you may need to do some work to get it correct, but this is how I use asp.net identity to create roles.